# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'RequestCompleted' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Anyone got any ideas?

The above error occurs when the following code is run:

```
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(RequestCompleted);
```

Within this block:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var postBackElement;

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(RequestCompleted);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequestHandler);

    function InitializeRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //set the postBackElement
        postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
    }
```

Comment: Well, where is the declaration of RequestCompleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `RequestCompleted` event if you're going to use it:

```
function RequestCompleted(sender, args) {
   // Do what you need to do here
}
```

If you don't need to handle the event, just remove this line from your markup:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(RequestCompleted);
```

Comment: Thanks - I was just coming back to say I'd worked it out - will put brain in gear before posting next time!

Comment: Deleted mine, +1 to yours.  No point having the same answer here twice :-)

Comment: @Andy E - Thanks mate. I did notice you posted about 26 seconds before me though :P. Sorry!

Comment: @Gen: no worries, it happens. Yours was slightly better anyway, I think :-)

Comment: @Andy E - Slightly off topic, you on Twitter?

Comment: @Gen: no :-) I avoid most forms of social networking - I even rarely use my Facebook.  This is about as social as it gets for me online ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need to do is emit a script block like this:

```
function RequestCompleted(sender, args) {
  alert("Finished AJAX");
}
```

Comment: Giving the same answer 5 mins after two other identical answers is not usually the polite thing to do.

Comment: Being rude isn't either.
When I started writing my response I had left my comment and there were no other answers.